# c++ bitset not inlined?

Tags: c++, g++, bitset

I try out the below:

```
#include <bitset>

int main ()
{
    std::bitset<32> bit32 { 0xf0f0f0f0 };
    bit32[4].flip();
    bit32[0] = 1;
}
```

Using GCC 4.8.1, I couldn't get it to inline, objdump gave me more or less:

```
  401536:   c7 45 e4 f0 f0 f0 f0    movl   $0xf0f0f0f0,-0x1c(%ebp)
  40153d:   8d 45 e8                lea    -0x18(%ebp),%eax
  401540:   c7 44 24 04 04 00 00    movl   $0x4,0x4(%esp)
  401547:   00 
  401548:   8d 55 e4                lea    -0x1c(%ebp),%edx
  40154b:   89 14 24                mov    %edx,(%esp)
  40154e:   89 c1                   mov    %eax,%ecx
  401550:   e8 93 13 00 00          call   4028e8 <__ZNSt6bitsetILj32EEixEj>
  401555:   83 ec 08                sub    $0x8,%esp
  401558:   8d 45 e8                lea    -0x18(%ebp),%eax
  40155b:   89 c1                   mov    %eax,%ecx
  40155d:   e8 b2 12 00 00          call   402814 <__ZNSt6bitsetILj32EE9reference4flipEv>
  401562:   8d 45 e8                lea    -0x18(%ebp),%eax
  401565:   89 c1                   mov    %eax,%ecx
  401567:   e8 10 13 00 00          call   40287c <__ZNSt6bitsetILj32EE9referenceD1Ev>
  40156c:   8d 45 f0                lea    -0x10(%ebp),%eax
  40156f:   c7 44 24 04 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,0x4(%esp)
  401576:   00 
  401577:   8d 55 e4                lea    -0x1c(%ebp),%edx
  40157a:   89 14 24                mov    %edx,(%esp)
  40157d:   89 c1                   mov    %eax,%ecx
  40157f:   e8 64 13 00 00          call   4028e8 <__ZNSt6bitsetILj32EEixEj>
  401584:   83 ec 08                sub    $0x8,%esp
  401587:   8d 45 f0                lea    -0x10(%ebp),%eax
  40158a:   c7 04 24 01 00 00 00    movl   $0x1,(%esp)
  401591:   89 c1                   mov    %eax,%ecx
  401593:   e8 f0 12 00 00          call   402888 <__ZNSt6bitsetILj32EE9referenceaSEb>
  401598:   83 ec 04                sub    $0x4,%esp
  40159b:   8d 45 f0                lea    -0x10(%ebp),%eax
  40159e:   89 c1                   mov    %eax,%ecx
  4015a0:   e8 d7 12 00 00          call   40287c <__ZNSt6bitsetILj32EE9referenceD1Ev>
  4015a5:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  4015aa:   8b 4d fc                mov    -0x4(%ebp),%ecx
```

-O1, -O2, -O3 doesn't help either, it sort of optimize away the code entirely.
Is there anyway I can avoid calling functions?

Comment: Why is calling functions causing problems?

Comment: @EdHeal : I'm sure it's much slower than what it ought to optimize to (ie. one `movl` instruction, as it did for me).  That might not be a big deal for this tiny test case, but if it's in performance critical code in a loop somewhere, it would make all the difference.

Comment: So, your problem is that the code is unoptimized unless you tell the compiler to optimize, in which case it optimizes it?

Answer (score 5):

Compile with optimizations enabled.  When I compile with `g++ -std=c++11 -O3` and the following slightly modified code, it outputs very optimized code:

Input:

```
#include <bitset>

volatile unsigned long v;

int main ()
{
    std::bitset<32> bit32 { 0xf0f0f0f0 };
    bit32[4].flip();
    bit32[0] = 1;

    v = bit32.to_ulong();
}
```

Compiler output:

```
main:
.LFB958:
    .cfi_startproc
    movl    $4042322145, %eax
    movq    %rax, v(%rip)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

I needed to add the `volatile` variable to keep G++ from optimizing it completely away.  It basically optimized all of the `bitset` operations down to a single `movl` instruction.

Applying @GlennTeitelbaum's suggestion below, I also ran a second test.  This one eliminates the `volatile` variable by initializing the `bitset` from `argc`, and returning the computed value from `main`:

```
#include <bitset>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    std::bitset<32> bit32 = argc;
    bit32[4].flip();
    bit32[0] = 1;

    return bit32.to_ulong();
}
```

This one generated the following compiler output (same flags as above):

```
main:
.LFB958:
    .cfi_startproc
    movl    %edi, %eax
    xorl    $16, %eax
    orq $1, %rax
    ret
```

Notice that it did optimize down to the minimum number of computational steps (`xorl` followed by `orl`) that are necessary when you don't know the actual initializer value to the `bitset` at compile time.  The third instruction (`movl %edi, %eax`) is there just to move `argc` from the register it arrives in to the register that the result will be returned in.

Comment: try initializing the bitset with argc, and then returning v

Answer (score 2):

Why use bitset if you are worried about calling functions?

How about

```
unsigned int bit32; // Assume int is 32 bits

bit32 = 0xf0f0f0f0;
bit32 ^= 16;
bit32 |= 1;
```

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum - XOR flips bits

Comment: Oops - missed the 4 bit

Comment: @JoeZ - Just though of that myself as it atarts counting from zero. The idea is sound though